# Close a SqueezeBox by id

Tags: php, javascript, joomla1.7, squeezebox

Well google this but I' did not found much
I'm using joomla 1.7
I have a main form I'd like to open a popup
so I have this code

```
$url ="index.php?option=com_tkgest&view=devis_ligne&is_popup=true&tmpl=component";
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 500, y: 300}}" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="modal" target="_blank">
   <img class="button-20" src="../media/com_tkgest/images/icon-32-search.png" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TKGEST_CHERCHER_PRODUIT'); ?>" />
</a>
```

well this will open the '`devis_ligne`' popup 
in the devis_ligne popup I have that same code to open onther popup let's call it product

in the product popup I chose one product in from this a list an then I execute this code

`window.parent.SqueezeBox.close()` to close the product but unfortunately that close the tow popup the product one and the `devis_ligne` and that's not what I'm looking for

maybe I should give an id for each popup or I don't know how to fix that

Thanks